# I have an error in docker-compose about undefined network,

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, streamlit

I am trying to dockerize two applications, one being streamlit, the other being fastapi, I have built the individual docker images for them, and now trying to run them at the same time so they communicate using docker-compose.
I have written the code but get an error when i run docker-compose up --build, that says
ERROR: Service "backend" uses an undefined network "AIservice"
because of this part of the code
networks:
AIservice:
aliases:
- backend.docker

how do i fix this error

Comment: Have you defined the network "Alservice" ?, before you can use the network needs to be defined, issue `docker network ls` command and provide the output.

Comment: For 99% of cases, it works to just delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  Compose provides a network named `default` that will be used automatically.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: Can you please provide the docker-compose file